# Page Breaks In Excel VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm working with the Office Interop and having trouble inserting page breaks in Excel. My code is working fine with the `horizontal page break` but I also need to set the `vertical pagebreak`. 
Can somone modify my code below, to make a `vertical page break` on `column I`?

This code is making the correct `horizontal pagebreaks` but is still 150 pages long because the vertical pagebreak is not set correctly.

```
Dim r As Excel.Range = CType(xlWorkSheet.Cells(27, 1), Excel.Range)

r.PageBreak = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the vertical pagebreak for the right Column object itself, rather than the cells range.

Comment: can you give me an example on how to do that?

Comment: something like:

Dim theColumn As Excel.Range = theWorksheet.Columns(1)

theColumn.PageBreak = Excel.XlPageBreak.xlPageBreakManual

Answer (score 4):

This

```
sheet.VPageBreaks.Add(sheet.Range["J1"]);
```

worked for me to set a vertical page break. As shown in the picture, it seems to put the page break before the specified column:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want page like A1:D15
for that

```
excelWorksheet.Range(E16).PageBreak = 1
```

It will create both vertical and horizontal page break.

This is just example. Code accordingly.