# .NET Print Area and PageBreak

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a code that prints an Excel file. This file must have two sheets. the problem is I cannot to set the page break for page number one.

Here's the code and the print

```
varExcelHoja.PageSetup.Zoom = False
varExcelHoja.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
varExcelHoja.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 2
varExcelHoja.PageSetup.PrintArea = "B1:J224"

varExcelHoja.PageSetup.LeftMargin = 0
varExcelHoja.PageSetup.RightMargin = 0
varExcelHoja.PageSetup.TopMargin = 0
varExcelHoja.PageSetup.BottomMargin = 0
varExcelHoja.PageSetup.HeaderMargin = 0
varExcelHoja.PageSetup.FooterMargin = 0
```

[image]

The dashed line located in Row 124 has to be on Row 130. How can I do it?
The code could be in C# too.

This is different from [Page Breaks In Excel VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518185/page-breaks-in-excel-vb-net) post, due to HPageBreaks and VPageBreaks works in a different way. Also, I have tried to change the Row to manual `varExcelHoja.Rows(124).PageBreak = -4135` and it doesn't work. I also have tried with `varExcelHoja.HPageBreaks(1).Location` but the same result. To make the Location property works I have changed `varExcelHoja.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 2` to `varExcelHoja.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = False`. The result is to have three sheets and I need just two sheets.

Regards

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518185/page-breaks-in-excel-vb-net

Answer (score 0):

I can add a horizontal page break like this:

```
varExcelHoja.HPageBreaks.Add(varExcelHoja.Range["A42"]);
```